# Execute jar in ubuntu including dll library

Tags: java, ubuntu, dll

Good day. I have the following problem. I have a code of application written on Java, which uses external jar library(no sources). This jar library inside loads external native library, which is set up with java.library.path system property. This external native library is DLL. The problem is to run this program in Ubuntu. Ubuntu wants to see not .dll as a library, but .so and there is no .so file available for this program, only .dll. Is there any way to convert .dll to .so or run this program using wine(Ubuntu tool), for example, some how, or any other way?
Will be very thank for help

Answer (score 2):

A .dll file is a **Windows** format library.  You might be able to run it under a Windows emulator in Linux (such as Wine) but there is no way to use it in a native Linux application.